# Filename is not being printed correctly as a part of subdirectory name is also appended to the filename in the output using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

**Structure**

```
│   afile.md
│   script.sh
│
└───somelongdirectoryname
        bfile.md
```

**script.sh**

​

```
find . -type f -name "*.md" -print | while read file_name
do
    basename=$file_name
    echo "  
title: \"$basename\"
" | sed -e "s/.md//g" | sed -e "s/.\///g" > "$basename.tmp"
    cat "$file_name" >> "$basename.tmp"
    mv "$basename.tmp" "$file_name"
done
```

**afile.md** and **bfile.md** are initially empty.

After running script:

**sh script.sh**

**Result**:

afile.md

```
title: "afile"
```

bfile.md (under a subdirectory somelongdirectoryname)

```
title: "somelongdirectorynambfile"
```

**Expected** result of bfile.md was:

```
title: "bfile"
```

Notice how in the bfile.md the subdirectory name in appended to the start (which is NOT expected) and for some reason the **e** in **somelongdirectorynam** is cut off as you can see in the output! (which is again weird to me.)

My objective is to fill the files in all subdirectories (and their subdirectories) recursively with some textual content with a bash script.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this script?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `sed -e "s/.\///g"` with `sed -e 's/".*\//"/'`. But, your whole script can be reduced to a single `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.md' -exec bash -c \
       't=${1##*/}; printf "\ntitle: \"%s\"\n\n" "${t%.md}" > "$1"' _ {} \;
```